# How to identify an event stream?

Tags: event-sourcing

I recently started discovering event sourcing so I am fairly new on the subject.

Imagine having a system (**system A**) which listens to events of a third party order service (**system B**). These events can be "OrderCreated", "OrderAmountUpdated", "OrderClosed", etc..

I want system A to build up an order entity based on the events coming from system B using event sourcing. The setup I have in mind is that for each unique order, a stream of events is created. The stream would have a guid as unique identifier and a collection of events.

Events coming from system B have an orderId property which is known on the order entity in system A as *externalOrderId*. To retrieve an event stream for an order, I want to avoid iterating over all the existing streams, building up the order they represent to then check if the *externalOrderId* is equal to the orderId of the event that just came in.

The "OrderCreated"-event is supposed to be the first event of an order. So when receiving this event, a new stream is created. Now upon receiving a second event for the same order, what is the recommended way to get the existing stream for that order?

Comment: How do you store the order streams? If every event has the external order id as an attribute, using that as a unique identifier for the stream (in addition to the UUID) should make identifying the stream trivial.

Comment: I was planning to use MongoDB and store the order streams in a collection. Indeed, making the external order id available on the stream itself makes this trivial. Thanks!